# Mac OS Sierra: Auto Complete Not Working In TeXShop

Tags: mac, texshop, auto-completion

After upgrading my Mac to macOS Sierra, I have an issue relating to BibDesk (v. 1.6.7) completions in TeXShop (v. 3.73); they don't work.
Previously, if I typed "\ref{" or "\cite{" and (while BibDesk was open) pressed Esc it would give me a list of all possible options contained in my document, but after upgrading to Sierra it isn't working at all.

Is anyone else having this problem, or a fix for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key has been used (by default---it can be configured to be the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) as the trigger key for command completion, NOT for filling in \cite commands. You use the <kbd>F5</kbd> key for filling in `\cite` commands with the `.bib file(s)` open in *BibDesk*.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how I can change it from F5? Before the update I had it as ESC!

Comment: I'm not sure but if you change the Command Completion trigger key to Tab (TeXShop->Preferences->Source has an item to do that) it the Esc key might revert to the BibDesk plugin. If that doesn't work I don't think it can be done.

Comment: There is no BibDesk plugin anymore, just to be pedantic; the keybinding is controlled by TeXShop or your system's bindings, and the code for communication with BibDesk is compiled into TeXShop. The standard one for `complete:` is option-escape, as it ties into the system's normal dictionary-based autocompletion for text views. You can confirm this yourself in TextEdit.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell I know it's not truly a plugin. I used the term lightly to mean it was supplied by the BibDesk project and is included in TeXShop.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Option-ESC doesn't seem to work in TeXShop, and simple ESC used to work just fine but now doesn't.  So something has changed.

Comment: @AlanMunn Look at `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBindings.dict` to see if it has a line like `"\033" = "complete:"; /*escape */`.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell I don't even have that directory in my `~/Library`

Comment: @AlanMunn In that case, I've no idea why Esc ever worked, as I don't use TeXShop. I've glanced at TeXShop's code for text input, and it's extremely…organic.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Ok. Thanks. I'll email Dick and ask what might have happened. For the moment the F5 does the trick; I just need to retrain my hand movements. :)

Comment: Have admit I've always used F5. @AlanMunn if you use TeXShop you must have ~/Library\TeXShop. In recent versions of TeXShop there is even a menu item under the File menu.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Given that I've contributed code to TeXShop, it's likely I use it. :) But Adam and I were discussing `~/Library/KeyBindings` not `~/Library/TeXShop`.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Sorry about that. The ~/Library/KeyBindings directory doesn't exist by default. Pick up `KeyBindings/zip` from [https://herbs.github.io](https://herbs.github.io) for more information. NOTE: Key bindings set there are global for all applications that use the Apple Text Frameworks (e.g., Mail, TeXShop).

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thanks.  But something has changed, since I have never had to deal with such a file in the past.  And your file doesn't do anything with the problem at hand, as far as I can see.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I understand it doesn't help in this case. I don't know why but I have always used F5 for bibliography/cross reference lookup via BibDesk.

Comment: Adding `KeyBindings/zip` from https://herbs.github.io as suggested by Herb Schulz and adding the line `"\033" = "complete:"; /*escape */` solved the issue for me. The Esc key trigers the filling of the \cite and \ref commands again.
So, thanks !

Comment: @ArnaudTriay-Alcouffe this worked for me too. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you folks changed the Command Completion trigger key to Tab also? If not, that addition to KeyBindings may override Command Completion.

Comment: @HerbSchulz this has not changed my Command Completion key - this is still Tab (for me anyway!)